# Unit testing Dapper/SqlConnection queries

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dapper

I have the following service that I would like to create unit tests for

```
public class Service
{
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPeople(string connString)
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        await conn.OpenAsync();
        return await conn.QueryAsync<Person>("SELECT * FROM People");
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I will be passing a connection string to connect to the db.
I know I need to create a in-memory database, then create the db structure, then table, then insert some data, then query using the service.

I tried using InMemoryDatabase but that seems to geared towards EF Code

My question how do I create unit tests for above code that would run in memory as this will also run azure.

Comment: What will you be testing? There is no logic in the service. I suppose you have more code, but that might be tested without the database. If you in reality are writing an integration test, you should use the right database provider.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to do some refactoring to properly unit test that class.

1. Pass the `connString` as constructor argument, it shouldn't be part of the interface.
2. Extract an interface `IService` with a `GetPeople` method.
3. Either use substitute implementation which returns a sequence of persons from an in-memory collection or use a framework like `Moq` to configure the expected behavior of `IService.GetPeople` to return a sequence of `Person`